# Activity.getReferrer() is only getting app Uri, not web referrer URL

Tags: android

When I analyze Deep Links coming into my Android App via a VIEW Intent, one thing I can look into is Activity.getReferrer(). I was hoping, that when the user comes from the browser (like the chrome browser), I might use getReferrer() to get the website URL, the user came from. Instead getReferrer() only gives me the app URI of chrome: "android-app://com.android.chrome"

Is there any other way to retrieve the website URL, the user came from?